# Ubuntu Server keeps using old kernel

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, grub2

I have a VPS running Ubuntu Server. I have installed Kernel 5.3.0-18 and tried different approaches but no matter what I do Ubuntu keeps booting Kernel 3.10.0. I did recently upgrade from Xenial to Focal.

uname -sr

```
Linux 3.10.0
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

dpkg --list | grep linux-image

```
ii  linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic  5.3.0-18.19+1  amd64   Signed kernel image generic
```

update-grub

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-18-generic
done
```

I did run

```
update-initramfs -u
```

and tried

```
grub-set-default
grub-reboot
```

but after a reboot uname -sr still returns Linux 3.10.0.

Is there any other way I can get (or force) Ubuntu to boot the newer kernel, I'd really like to be able to install kernel modules again.

Comment: Is your vps service a "low cost" one? Is it described as openviz? Many low cost VPS offerings are based on technology that is closer to containers than full virtual machines. Are you sure that you have the correct filesystem mounted at /boot?

Comment: I believe the provider ([delta-networks](https://delta-networks.de/) ) is using OpenVZ7. How would I go about checking wether the correct filesystem is mounted at /boot?

Comment: openvz technology doesn't allow running an other kernel than openvz's. it's container technology, not virtual machine. Kernel might not belong to you but only to your provider (it's not loaded from your container anyway).

Comment: If you really want to change the kernel about the best you can do  apart from changing provider is run software to simulate a machine. QEMU is the best known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by icarus and A.B. it was due to the provider using OpenVZ.

I have since switched providers (to a provider using KVM) and the problem is gone.